# Apache Camel -- Reference type constants in Spring DSL

Tags: spring, apache-camel, hazelcast

I'm trying to define a publish operation to Hazelcast topic using Spring DSL

```
<from uri="direct:inbound" />      
        <onCompletion>
            <log message="onCompletion:- ${body}" />
            <setHeader headerName="${type:org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.HazelcastConstants.OPERATION}">
                <simple>${type:org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.HazelcastConstants.PUBLISH_OPERATION}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="hazelcast:topic:foo" />
        </onCompletion>                                                
        <log message="${body}" />
```

The above route works, but I have to use long SIMPLE scripts like "${type:org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.HazelcastConstants.OPERATION}" to ref a constant value. Is there any simpler or short form for this?

I tried to define a spring bean for HazelcastConstants class and ref it through SIMPLE scripts as below but it's not working with MethodNotFoundException "Method with name: OPERATION not found on bean"

```
<bean id="hazelcastConstants" class="org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.HazelcastConstants" />
... ...
<simple>${bean:hazelcastConstants.OPERATION}</simple>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bean workaround would work, if you defined a bean contained a method returning the constant in question, e.g.:

```
public class ContantRetriever() {
  public String getHazelCastOperation() {
   return org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.HazelcastConstants.PUBLISH_OPERATION;
  }
}
```

Your Spring context:

```
<bean id="hazelcastConstants" class="yourpackage.ContantRetriever"/>
<simple>${bean:hazelcastConstants.getHazelCastOperation}</simple>
```

If that is no good for you, I am afraid you are stuck with the long form of accessing constants.